# What is required to sell books in the US and UK from another country via CreateSpace?

Tags: publishing, self-publishing, print-on-demand

I have recently completed my adventure/fantasy novel. I am planning to self-publish it via CreateSpace's POD option.

I am from India and want to sell my book in various countries, but could find no mention of it on the CreateSpace site...

So my question is what (if any) are the legal and/or licensing requirements to sell in the US and UK via Amazon's CreateSpace service?

Comment: You may already be doing this, but just a bit of advice - using an editor that is a native English speaker would probably be a very good idea if your novel is written in English.  The language in your question above makes it obvious that you're a non-native English speaker.  That's not really a problem - there have been many great novelists that were born speaking different languages.  Just edit it before you try to sell it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely none, except filling in a US taxation report (this can be done inside the CreateSpace website). It sounds complicated but it isn't the system guides you through